# Is there a way to change HTML content of a <p> element from within a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, scope, innerhtml

I want to change the HTML content of my webpage from within a javascript function. My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="chartInfo">
  <p id="last_updated">Hello</p>
</div>
```

My Javascript function is a QueryResponse to a GoogleCharts query. It looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

function function_1() {
    var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT AA, AB');
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dXP9yGEzNlmRxwCr2kyMM9CcS5hloIxKvef0RSa10/gviz/tq?gid=559927965&headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
      query.send(function_2);    
      };

function function_2(response) {
      if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      };
      var data = response.getDataTable();
      var t = (data.getvalue(0,0));
      var latest_time = t.getDate()
      document.getElementById("last_updated").innerHTML = "Last updated: " + latest_time;
      };

</script>
```

Currently the webpage is showing "Hello" rather than "Last Updated: " + latest_time as I want it to.

I think it may be a problem of scope - when I write scripts out underneath I can change it from "Hello" to another string using document.getElementById, but then I can't access the variable latest_time which is within function_2.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You define `function_1` but you never do anything with it. Why should it have any effect?

Comment: Your code updating `innerHTML` is one of the ways to do this, and your `getElementById` call is correct. Do you ever call `function_1`? Does the query complete and call `function_2`? What do you see in the browser console and/or network tab?

Comment: Yes this function   ---    function refreshIframe1D() {
       var frame = document.getElementById("Frame");
       frame.src = "https://www.someurl.co.uk";
       function_1(frame.src);   ---  is called when the page loads, so I think that should mean function_1 and function_2 are called?

Answer (score -3):

Change dom.innerHTML to dom.textContent for changing text of it

Comment: While this is good advice in general (when the input isn't known-safe HTML), I don't see how it solves the problem. If `innerHTML` currently has no effect then changing that to `innerText` won't either.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but as Quentin said this still doesn't have an effect on the <p> element. innerHTML works when outside of function_2, but I need to use the variables from function_2, and I can't find a way to pull the local variables into the global scope

Comment: I missed the topic, sorry

Comment: hellikiam thanks anyway! Good general advice as Quentin said

Comment: @HL589 In order to pull local variables to the global scope, you could either declare it globally, or pass those variables into another function as parameters

Comment: @KienHT Good idea. I've been trying to do that by writing `var latest_time;` just above function_1 and then deleting `var` before `latest_time` in function_2, but it still says latest_time is undefined. Am I doing it right or how can I correct it?

Comment: @HL589 Yes you did it right. When you declare it globally like: `var lastest_time;` on top of the other two functions, Javascript will automatically initialize it to `undefined` which is same thing you got. So I think the `function_2` never run. You want to console.log() to see if it actually runs or not

Comment: @KienHT okay thank you very much. Seems like it's not running. How can I call it? In a separate script below (where `document.GetElementById` worked to change the <p> element to 'Latest time: undefined'), I tried writing `function_2()` and `function_1()` to call them but then the <p> element just shows 'Hello'

Comment: @HL589 Is there any errors? Could you share your codes on https://jsfiddle.net/ please? It will be easier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225826/discussion-between-hl589-and-kienht).